# How to store an image in Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, file, storage

I'm learning and tried to follow a bunch of guides but I just can't seem to store it in the right directory if at all.

So my storage structure is like this:
storage -> app-> public -> books

Please tell me how I can store an image named $isbn in the 'books' folder like storage -> app-> public -> books -> $isbn.jpg

Thank you.

I tried:

```
$image = $request->file('imgInp');
Storage::disk('local')->put('books/'.$isbn, $image, 'public');
```

All this did was store the image (that is not named $isbn) like storage -> app-> books -> $isbn -> image_with_weird_name.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getClientOriginalExtension() method to get the extension of the original file and concatenating it with the $isbn to form the filename.

```
$image = $request->file('imgInp');
$filename = $isbn . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // set filename to $isbn.jpg
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('books', $image, $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$request->file('imgInp')->storeAs(
    'books', $isbn, ['disk' => 'public']
);
```

Or:

```
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(
    'books', $request->file('imgInp'), $isbn
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$image = $request->file('imgInp')
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('books', $image, $isbn);
```